# How to combine filter conditions in Polars?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-polars

In this example Pokémon data, let's say we want to exclude any Pokémon that is both Type 1 = Dragon and Total = 600. That means we want to exclude just one record (highlighted below):

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ritchie46/cac6b337ea52281aa23c049250a4ff03/raw/89a957ff3919d90e6ef2d34235e6bf22304f3366/pokemon.csv")
df = df.sort("Total", descending=True)
df
┌─────┬───────────────────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬───────┬─────┬────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬───────┬────────────┬───────────┐
│ #   ┆ Name                      ┆ Type 1  ┆ Type 2  ┆ Total ┆ HP  ┆ Attack ┆ Defense ┆ Sp. Atk ┆ Sp. Def ┆ Speed ┆ Generation ┆ Legendary │
│ --- ┆ ---                       ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ str                       ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ i64   ┆ i64 ┆ i64    ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64   ┆ i64        ┆ bool      │
╞═════╪═══════════════════════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═══════╪═════╪════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═══════╪════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 150 ┆ Mewtwo                    ┆ Psychic ┆ null    ┆ 680   ┆ 106 ┆ 110    ┆ 90      ┆ 154     ┆ 90      ┆ 130   ┆ 1          ┆ true      │
│ 130 ┆ GyaradosMega Gyarados     ┆ Water   ┆ Dark    ┆ 640   ┆ 95  ┆ 155    ┆ 109     ┆ 70      ┆ 130     ┆ 81    ┆ 1          ┆ false     │
│ 6   ┆ CharizardMega Charizard X ┆ Fire    ┆ Dragon  ┆ 634   ┆ 78  ┆ 130    ┆ 111     ┆ 130     ┆ 85      ┆ 100   ┆ 1          ┆ false     │
│ 6   ┆ CharizardMega Charizard Y ┆ Fire    ┆ Flying  ┆ 634   ┆ 78  ┆ 104    ┆ 78      ┆ 159     ┆ 115     ┆ 100   ┆ 1          ┆ false     │
│ 9   ┆ BlastoiseMega Blastoise   ┆ Water   ┆ null    ┆ 630   ┆ 79  ┆ 103    ┆ 120     ┆ 135     ┆ 115     ┆ 78    ┆ 1          ┆ false     │
│ 3   ┆ VenusaurMega Venusaur     ┆ Grass   ┆ Poison  ┆ 625   ┆ 80  ┆ 100    ┆ 123     ┆ 122     ┆ 120     ┆ 80    ┆ 1          ┆ false     │
│ 142 ┆ AerodactylMega Aerodactyl ┆ Rock    ┆ Flying  ┆ 615   ┆ 80  ┆ 135    ┆ 85      ┆ 70      ┆ 95      ┆ 150   ┆ 1          ┆ false     │
│ 94  ┆ GengarMega Gengar         ┆ Ghost   ┆ Poison  ┆ 600   ┆ 60  ┆ 65     ┆ 80      ┆ 170     ┆ 95      ┆ 130   ┆ 1          ┆ false     │
│ 127 ┆ PinsirMega Pinsir         ┆ Bug     ┆ Flying  ┆ 600   ┆ 65  ┆ 155    ┆ 120     ┆ 65      ┆ 90      ┆ 105   ┆ 1          ┆ false     │
│ 149 ┆ ***Dragonite***           ┆*Dragon* ┆ Flying  ┆*600*  ┆ 91  ┆ 134    ┆ 95      ┆ 100     ┆ 100     ┆ 80    ┆ 1          ┆ false     │
│ 65  ┆ AlakazamMega Alakazam     ┆ Psychic ┆ null    ┆ 590   ┆ 55  ┆ 50     ┆ 65      ┆ 175     ┆ 95      ┆ 150   ┆ 1          ┆ false     │
│ …   ┆ …                         ┆ …       ┆ …       ┆ …     ┆ …   ┆ …      ┆ …       ┆ …       ┆ …       ┆ …     ┆ …          ┆ …         │
│ 14  ┆ Kakuna                    ┆ Bug     ┆ Poison  ┆ 205   ┆ 45  ┆ 25     ┆ 50      ┆ 25      ┆ 25      ┆ 35    ┆ 1          ┆ false     │
│ 129 ┆ Magikarp                  ┆ Water   ┆ null    ┆ 200   ┆ 20  ┆ 10     ┆ 55      ┆ 15      ┆ 20      ┆ 80    ┆ 1          ┆ false     │
│ 10  ┆ Caterpie                  ┆ Bug     ┆ null    ┆ 195   ┆ 45  ┆ 30     ┆ 35      ┆ 20      ┆ 20      ┆ 45    ┆ 1          ┆ false     │
│ 13  ┆ Weedle                    ┆ Bug     ┆ Poison  ┆ 195   ┆ 40  ┆ 35     ┆ 30      ┆ 20      ┆ 20      ┆ 50    ┆ 1          ┆ false     │
└─────┴───────────────────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴───────┴─────┴────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴───────┴────────────┴───────────┘
```

I would try to remove this one row like this:

```
df.filter(pl.col("Type 1") != "Dragon" & pl.col("Total") != 600)
```

but this gives a `TypeError: the truth value of an Expr is ambiguous`.

If we change to `.ne()` then it runs, but it's removing anything that is a Dragon and removing anything with a Total score of 600 (5 records), when we instead want to remove anything that is BOTH a Dragon and a Total score of 600 (1 record).

```
df.filter(pl.col("Type 1").ne("Dragon") & pl.col("Total").ne(600))
```

What is the proper way to combine multiple filter conditions like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is happening because when you use multiple conditions you need to wrap then in parenthesis.

Nevertheless to get rid of that single line the proper way is:

```py
df.filter((pl.col("Type 1") != "Dragon") | (pl.col("Total") != 600))
```

Using a parenthesis over both conditions, and use instead of & the operator | (OR) operator to retain the records that don't meet either of these conditions, you only exclude the records that are both 'Dragon' and have a Total of 600.

Comment: I think the OP want's & rather than | here, but otherwise nice, concise answer.

Comment: Using & in this answer ends up removing too many rows, the | removes just the one. Seems a bit counterintuitive, but it works.

Comment: @Alastair, I initially thought the and (&) operator was correct, but it was not filtering a single row, as the OP asked. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @bbgatch You can also phrase it in "reverse" and add `.not_()` at the end e.g. `df.filter(pl.all_horizontal(pl.col("Type 1") == "Dragon", pl.col("Total") == 600).not_())`

Comment: Yes that might be more intuitive :)

Comment: The `&` `|` syntax is slightly faster than `all`/`any_horizontal`. You can also negate with the `~` symbol. For instance `df.filter(~((pl.col('Type 1')=='Dragon') & (pl.col('Total')!=600)))`

Comment: The issue, btw, is that python's order of operations has`|` and `&`before the equality checking so without the parenthesis, python sees it like `df.filter(pl.col("Type 1") != ("Dragon" & pl.col("Total")) != 600)` which, of course, doesn't make sense.